# Rearrange matrix based on column "bins"

Tags: r

I have a [6,2] matrix that I want to rearrange the rows by the two column "bins":

I would like to output a descending order of `[,1]` "bins" then a descending order of `[,2]` based on the "bin" of `[,1]`. Ideally, I would not define the "bins", but it's ok if I do. The example below illustrates what I mean:

```
Example input

# [,1] has 3 bins
# [,2] has 2 bins


           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,]  968.3885  438.3863
 [2,]  950.4227 1862.5566

 [3,]  232.5512  488.0292
 [4,]  245.5995 1828.5346

 [5,]  445.5995 1838.5346
 [6,]  412.4362  446.0405
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Example input

           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,]  950.4227 1862.5566
 [2,]  968.3885  438.3863

 [3,]  445.5995 1838.5346
 [4,]  412.4362  446.0406

 [5,]  245.5995 1828.5346
 [6,]  232.5512  488.0292
```

`[,1]` needs to be bined into 3 bins, then within the bin, have a descending order of `[,2]`

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: *`Ideally, I would not define the "bins"`* ... okay, how should they be inferred? 100s? Is it always 3 bins, regardless of the number of rows? Clusters of data?

Comment: @r2evans I am think of a non-supervised method - something like Jenks breaks. Again, I have ways to extract the number of bins, so this is if anyone got input.

Comment: SO isn't a free code-service, perhaps you can try some clustering yourself and come back with specifics about it?

Comment: @r2evans I don't need a code-service - I need input/perspective. I have attempted a cluster [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BAMMtools/versions/2.1.7/topics/getJenksBreaks) and trying different things currently. From your input and other comments I got, it can greatly change my approach because I do lack the background.

Comment: Given your matrix (`M`), are you expecting some function `f()` to map elements of `M[,1]` to a bin number?  For example, `f <- function(x, bin_size = 100){as.integer(x / bin_size)}`.  Then if you want a list of submatrices, I suspect `lapply` and `split` can be used to segment your matrix into bins, according to the vectorized value of `f(M[,1])`. Alternatively, if you just want a single `matrix`, convert `M` to a `data.frame` for `group`ing or `sort`ing manipulations with the `dplyr` package, and convert the result back into a `matrix`.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the input - I should be able to use `dplyr` to group and sort. I can also define`bin_size`  in the function as you suggested. Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help, and good luck!  Just a quick caveat: if the values in `M[,1]` are not distributed evenly, but rather in a lopsided fashion, my `f()` will not necessarily map to 3 bins of equal size.  You might have to `dplyr::arrange()` by column 1, then bin by `row_number()`...but there are countless valid ways to do something like that.